# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=6.0.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget-package

I am getting the below exception after deploying the app on the server.

It's working as expected when running locally from visual studio.

I have removed the System.Threading.Channels reference as well from my project and deployed the app again. but same issue.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified. --->
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.Threading.Channels, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The
> system cannot find the file specified

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix the issue by adding the System.Threading.Channels 6.0.0.0 package from NuGet package.